# python regex for extracting strings between certain two strings

Tags: python, regex

Let's assume I have a string

```
st = "'aaa': '1', 'bbb': '2.3', 'ccc': 'name'"
```

I want to extract from st the following

```
['1', '2.3', 'name']
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing it with `ast` module would be best, like jezrael did it. Here is another solution with regex:

```
import re

st = "'a': '1', 'b': '2.3', 'c': 'name', 'd': 229, 'e': '', 'f': '228', 'g': 12"
print re.findall(r'\'\S+?\':\s*\'?(.*?)\'?(?:,|$)', st)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2.3', 'name', '229', '', '228', '12']
```

Demo on regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/zGAt4D/5

Comment: What is there is a number rather than string after ':' ?

Comment: @Mansumen Ok I'll improve it

Comment: @Mansumen Check now.

Comment: @Mansumen Made it more robust to include empty strings as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can first create `dict` by [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html) and then get `values`:

```
import ast

st = "'aaa': '1', 'bbb': '2.3', 'ccc': 'name'"

print (ast.literal_eval('{' + st + '}'))
{'aaa': '1', 'bbb': '2.3', 'ccc': 'name'}

#python 3 add list
print (list(ast.literal_eval('{' + st + '}').values()))
['1', '2.3', 'name']

#python 2
print ast.literal_eval('{' + st + '}').values()
['1', '2.3', 'name']
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there another way to do this with regular expression?

Comment: check another solution.